# Garbage disposal wiring to metal box

Tags: garbage-disposal

I installed a new garbage disposal and have two electrical boxes under my sink.  One is operated by switch running to the dishwasher, while the other is a metal box covered with a face plate.  This runs to a switch located on the back splash.  The problem, if it is a problem, I was going to make the box a plug in and simply plug in the disposal, yet only two wires come out.  Where is the ground?  I am sure it will work but is there not supposed to be a ground or is it grounded at the switch?  Yes I did properly ground the disposal itself.  Is this normal and should there be third wire??

Comment: If it was wired in the 60s or 70s it probably was done with non-grounded cable. You'll need to upgrade that.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box you want to use?

Comment: Should not the switch work the disposer and a continuous hot feed to the dishwasher???